# Should I ask this question about ie6 usage here?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about ie6 usage in stackoverflow.com. Should I ask it here instead?

The question is at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241001/when-will-ie6countdown-com-update-the-figures

I've read about "migrating questions". How would I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: The moderators of Stack Overflow will migrate it for you. We don't keep track of why individual sites are down or not being updated. You'll just have to wait until they update their site or reply to your email. There is always the option of finding a new IE6 figures site.

Comment: @user1345712: I think no! Your question is no fit for here, nor for SO. Read the Faq: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not a good fit for any of the StackExchange sites (SO or Webmasters in particular) because you can't expect members here to provide you with support for a website that is not under their control (`www.ie6countdown.com`). How can we know why they are late? (In addition, they now have the March figures, by the way.)

Contacting them directly would be the right approach.

Failing that, you might be able to rephrase your question to make it less specific to this site. For example:

> I'm developing a web-site for users in China. I would like to get
>   up-to-date statistics about IE6 usage there. The latest ones I have
>   seen on `www.ie6countdown.com` are for February. Is there there a more
>   up-to-date source of usage statistics?

(I'm not sure whether other users here would agree on this, so don't necessarily re-post this question straight away...)

More fundamentally, what do you expect really? Unless a major event happened that could have pushed a vast number of users to change their browsers, I don't think a month will make a big difference for this type of statistics (there was only a 3-week delay on these numbers). I've never heard anyone say "Winter is about to end, let's see whether there's a better browser out there."